# how to multiply two $row values that's been taken from database?

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch two different values from mysql database to website and then multiply them by each other and show on website by using echo attribute, but I think that I'm writing it wrong. how should I use multiply[*] between $row['amount'] and $row['price']?

I tried putting * in quotation marks or/and writing comma between * and $rows but it isn't working.

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY idUsers DESC LIMIT 1;";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $row['amount'] * $row['price'] . "<br>";
    }
  }

 ?>
```

I expect the output of amount * price, 3*2 to be 6 but the actual output is 3.

Comment: `var_dump($row);`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: your code seems correct, please check the values getting in $row['amount'] & $row['price']
You can also achieve by query :
SELECT 
    *, 
    amount * price as 'total_amount'
FROM clients ORDER BY idUsers DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to do the calculation in the database query. So you don`t need to do it in the output and also the output looks more clean.
Also make sure amount and price are numberformats and are not null or 0

```php
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT *, (amount * price) as totalprice FROM clients ORDER BY idUsers DESC LIMIT 1;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['totalprice'] . "<br>";
        } 
    }

?>
```

Hope that helps,
Timo

Answer (score 0):

Check weather the $row['amount'] and $row['price'] are int values or not before multipl them

Comment: they are both int values